# FileSystemWatcher - reasons for InternalBufferOverflow

Tags: filesystemwatcher

I want to confirm if the only way that FileSystemWatcher can throw a buffer overflow error is if it getting/processing too many files at once. I wan to make sure there isn't some slow creep of leftover garbage in the buffer that I need to address in some way.

I'm watching a number of folders with a process that gives me a buffer overflow every few weeks.  It threw the error much more often when it was only at 8K, I have it set to 64K now.  But I want to make sure that the only reason it's happening is if I indeed got a huge number of files, and not some memory creep issue that I need to address either in the code, or just by restarting the process periodically.